# How to solve this problem about VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

so i used this code

```
Set Rng = Sheets("COA").Range("i11:i39")
On Error Resume Next
    Set VisibleCells = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
If Not VisibleCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each aCell In VisibleCells
            Select Case aCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Case vbRed
    MsgBox "Terdapat data outspek. Periksa kembali!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
    'Show Excel and resize the UserForm2
    Application.Visible = True
    Me.Height = 405
    Me.Width = 730.5
    
    SaveButton.Enabled = False
    
    Case 16777215
    Unload UserForm2
    
    'Gets the name of the currently visible worksheet
    Filename = "COA" & Sheets("COA").Range("B1")

    'Puts the worksheet into its own workbook
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy

    'Saves the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename

    'Closes the newly created workbook so you are still looking at the original workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    End Select
    Next aCell
    End If
```

If there is a red cell then it will return to the userform.  cell I17 is not red, but why is it automatically saved in .xls format?  even though if there is a red cell, it cannot be saved in .xls format and must return to the userform.  can you guys help me?

Comment: You loop over all visible cells. The first visible cell in *not* red (but white) and therefore the code hits the second case branch where the file is saved. Use the debugger and execute the code step by step (use F8) to see how the code behaves.

Comment: What is the code? I am sorry bcs its my first time using vba. So i don't know how to code it

Comment: Sorry looks like I misunderstood your question. to loop through a range the easiest (but kind of slow) way to do it is: `Dim RG as range` > `Dim CL as range` > `Set RG = range("A1:F100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` > `for each CL in RG.cells` > `If CL.interior.color` ... whatever you're checking... `then` > ...do your thing... > `End if` > `Next CL`

Comment: I use your code but the cells that are not red are still counted, even though there are red cells

Answer (score 0):

Suggest something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    Dim rng As Range, Filename As String
    
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COA").Range("I11:I39")
    
    If HasVisibleRedCell(rng) Then   'call the function to check the range...
        MsgBox "Terdapat data outspek. Periksa kembali!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, ""
        Application.Visible = True
        Me.Height = 405
        Me.Width = 730.5
        Me.SaveButton.Enabled = False
    Else
        Unload UserForm2  'Me?
        Filename = "COA" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COA").Range("B1")
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy 
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename '<<< should use a full path here...
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
End Sub

'Does the range `rng` contain at least one visible red-filled cell?
Function HasVisibleRedCell(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim VisibleCells As Range, c As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set VisibleCells = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not VisibleCells Is Nothing Then 'any visible cells?
        For Each c In VisibleCells      'check each cell fill
            If c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
                HasVisibleRedCell = True  'found one
                Exit Function             'no need to check further
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    'if got here then by default returns False...
End Function
```